# Output from psycopg2 differs from command line

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, datetime

When I run `select now() - pg_last_xact_replay_timestamp() AS replication_delay` directly on the database, the output is

```
replication_delay
-------------------
 -00:00:00.55072
(1 row)
```

When I put the same query in a python script

```
import psycopg2

 try:
    connection = psycopg2.connect(user="postgres",
                              host="x.x.x.x",
                              port="5432",
                              database="postgres")

    cursor = connection.cursor()
    postgreSQL_select_Query = "select now() - pg_last_xact_replay_timestamp() AS 
    replication_delay;"

    cursor.execute(postgreSQL_select_Query)
    records = cursor.fetchall()
    print (records)

    except (Exception, psycopg2.Error) as error:
    print("Error while fetching data from PostgreSQL", error)

    finally:
    # closing database connection.
        if connection:
           cursor.close()
           connection.close()
           print("PostgreSQL connection is closed")
```

The output is

```
    [(datetime.timedelta(days=-1, seconds=86399, microseconds=521719),)]
```

How can I get the output from the script to display like the command line output?

```
 00:00:00.55072
```

Comment: `select (now() - pg_last_xact_replay_timestamp())::text AS replication_delay`

Comment: @AdrianKlaver thank you, worked, please post the answer so I can give you credit.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting an array of tuples because you're using `fetchall` to fetch all rows. Since you're only fetching one row, use `fetchone` to get just a tuple.

Then get the first item in the tuple.

```
cursor.execute(postgreSQL_select_Query)
records = cursor.fetchone()
delta = records[0]
```

Now you have just the time interval.

---

psycopg2 has mapped the Postgresql [interval type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html) to a [datetime.timedelta](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects) object. You need to format it. Problem is, there's no built in way to format a timedelta.

Worse, `datetime.timedelta(days=-1, seconds=86399, microseconds=521719` is a very, very strange way to represent -0.478281 seconds, but that's how timedelta works. Normally you'd just `str(delta)` to get what you want, but when we try the above we get `-1 day, 23:59:59.521719` which is not useful.

Instead, if it's negative take the absolute value (which will turn it into `datetime.timedelta(microseconds=478281)`), turn it into a string, and add the negative sign.

```
from datetime import timedelta
from math import modf

def format_timedelta(delta):
  if delta < timedelta(0):
    return "-" + str(abs(delta))
  else:
    return str(delta)
```

Answer (score 0):

As example:

```
select now() - (now() + '.55072 secs'::interval);
    ?column?     
-----------------
 -00:00:00.55072


--The type of the result.
select pg_typeof(now() - (now() - '.3925 secs'::interval));
 pg_typeof 
-----------
 interval
```

From here [Interval output](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-INTERVAL-OUTPUT) see *Table 8.18. Interval Output Style Examples*. The formatted value returned is going to depend on the `intervalstyle` setting. In the case above the default 'postgres` style is used:

```
show intervalstyle;
 IntervalStyle 
---------------
 postgres
```

This is heads up that if a different `intervalstyle is used the output will differ:

```
set intervalstyle = postgres_verbose;

select now() - (now() + '.55072 secs'::interval);
      ?column?      
--------------------
 @ 0.55072 secs ago
```